# PySpark: Why do regression models give different accuracy results on a single node setup vs multi node cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

The below code shows how I am creating the model pipeline, in this only the regressor changes. I am trying with Random Forest, Linear Regression, and GBT models but all of them show different results when executed in a single machine vs a cluster of machines. In both setups, exactly the same EMR cluster configuration is used with all the default setups.

```
def _create_training_pipeline(self, regressor_name, tuned_model=None):
    if tuned_model is None:
        tuned_model = {}
    stages = []
    for col in self._string_cols:
        indexer = StringIndexer() \
            .setInputCol(col) \
            .setHandleInvalid("skip") \
            .setOutputCol(col + "Index")
        stages += [indexer]

    for col in self._string_cols:
        encoder = OneHotEncoder() \
            .setInputCol(col + "Index") \
            .setOutputCol(col + "Vec")
        stages += [encoder]

    assembler = VectorAssembler() \
        .setInputCols([x + "Vec" for x in self._string_cols] + self._numerical_cols) \
        .setHandleInvalid("skip") \
        .setOutputCol("features")

    feature_indexer = VectorIndexer() \
        .setInputCol(assembler.getOutputCol()) \
        .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures") \
        .setHandleInvalid("skip") \
        .setMaxCategories(2)

    regressor = self._get_regressor(regressor_name, feature_indexer, tuned_model)

    stages += [assembler, feature_indexer, regressor]
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
    return pipeline

def _get_regressor(self, regressor_name, feature_indexer, params_dict):
    if regressor_name == "RFR":
        return RandomForestRegressor() \
            .setSeed(100) \
            .setLabelCol(self._label_column) \
            .setFeaturesCol(feature_indexer.getOutputCol()) \
            .setMaxDepth(params_dict.get("maxDepth", 5)) \
            .setNumTrees(params_dict.get("numTrees", 10)) \
            .setMinInstancesPerNode(params_dict.get("minInstancesPerNode", 2))
    elif regressor_name == "LR":
        return LinearRegression() \
            .setLabelCol(self._label_column) \
            .setFeaturesCol(feature_indexer.getOutputCol()) \
            .setMaxIter(params_dict.get("maxIter", 10)) \
            .setEpsilon(params_dict.get("epsilon", 2)) \
            .setRegParam(params_dict.get("regParam", 0.5))
    else:
        return GBTRegressor() \
            .setSeed(100) \
            .setLabelCol(self._label_column) \
            .setFeaturesCol(feature_indexer.getOutputCol()) \
            .setMaxIter(params_dict.get("maxIter", 50)) \
            .setMaxDepth(params_dict.get("maxDepth", 10))
```

A Probable issue could be distributed training vs single node training (couldn't find a source to back this up)

I have performed this test 20 times, to be certain of this observation. In my local machine, the results are matching with the results of a single node EMR setup.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed machine learning trade-offs are discussed under the heading Discretization Error Analysis by Firas Abuzaid et al:

> To improve efficiency, continuous features are instead commonly discretized to B discrete bins ... discretization heuristic results in the approximation of continuous values by discrete representatives, and can adversely impact the statistical performance of the resulting decision tree...

[Yggdrasil: An Optimized System for Training Deep Decision Trees at Scale](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ematei/papers/2016/nips_yggdrasil.pdf). Firas Abuzaid, Joseph Bradley, Feynman Liang, Andrew Feng, Lee Yang,Matei Zaharia, Ameet Talwalkar

This descretizing/binning approximation used by MLlib for distributed training isn't needed on a single node/local machine deployment. As a result, I would expect the statistical performance of the resulting model to be better for a model trained on a single node than the distributed case.